# Ender 3 failing on the same z position every print

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis, underextrusion

I have an Ender 3, I changed its extruder for one metallic one.
In my last prints, I am getting issues at the same height. The extruder can't pull the filament in for that z position.
I cleaned the Z axis, applied oil, and adjusted the eccentric nuts. I have minor improvements but still have many issues with my prints.
I am thinking of changing to double z-axis, but I'd like to use my printer now.

[image]
[image]

This is my printer.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing Stack!  Can you post a photo of your filament path?  This seems like you might have something jamming up your feed at a certain Z height.

Comment: Is it every print that fails at this Z height, or just *every attempt* of this particular print? Whatever it is, this is an extrusion issue, not a Z motion issue. The problem is not the rollers and will not be solved by dual Z.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I double-check the filament track. In theory I fixed it already.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE every print in the last three weeks have the same issue. You are right. I am gonna post more pics soon. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "In theory I fixed it already", if you fixed this please share through an answer. Both filament track and filament spool (winding) look too good to explain extra resistance caused by entanglement or kinks.

Comment: The extruder couldn't pull the filament. I had to pull the filament by hand every few minutes. That part was fixed. But my printings have errors yet. Around the same Z heights.

Comment: OK, based on the new pics you added this looks like a massive layer shift, vs what looked like an extrusion problem in the original post. So it may very well be something wrong in Z motion at that height, causing a nozzle collision and thereby layer shift.

Comment: I haven't fixed my 3d printer yet. I know what my problem is now. I am having flow continuity issues. I thought it was happening because my filament was wet. I tried with a new filament, and it's happening the same after a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue today on two printers.

One was failing first or second layer, the other after 1/2 an hour or so. After trying everything else I traced the cause to changing the nozzle to cheap steel ones. Changed back to the old brass ones and both printers are working fine.

Unsure what is wrong with the steel nozzles, I bought 10 of them online for peanuts, but happy to be printing again.

Comment: How did you determine that your issue was the same as OP's?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE because it looks like roughly the same description and has the steel nozzle change in common. I was looking at everything else before realising it was the brand new nozzles. Filaments, heat, levelling mechanicals etc,. Then finally fixed one today, and went straight home and fixed the other in a few minutes